# array.map does not change array values

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't array.map work?

My code is:

```
let myArray = [000,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999];

myArray.map((value) => {
     return = 1000 - value;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

The result is:
[0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]

Comment: The result *isn’t* that. `return =` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `map` returns a new array. It doesn't modify the old one in place. Do this instead:

```
let myArray = [000,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999];

let myNewArray = myArray.map((value) => {
     return 1000 - value;
});

console.log(myNewArray);
```